# Поиск максимального и минимального элементов двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c++

Как поменять местами максимальный и минимальный элемент?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int N;
    cout << "Введите размер квадратной матрицы N:";
    cin >> N;
    float **arr = new float *[N]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new float[N];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<N;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        {
            arr[i][j]=rand() % 100;
            cout << arr[i][j]<<"\t";
        }   
        cout << endl;
    }
    int max = arr[0][0];
    int min = max;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (max < arr[i][j])
                max = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout <<"MAX="<< max<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (min > arr[i][j])
                min = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "MIN=" <<min;
    cout << endl;
    
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И в чем проблема? Вы же правильно нашли минимум и максимум, только для того чтобы их местами поменять нужно запомнить их индексы

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Задача ведь решена. На первый взгляд, по крайней мере.

Comment: @ Rikitikitavi, я вводил две доп. переменные, в которые помещал номера строк (i). Но при их выводе они были одинаковые, хотя по положение mах и min они не должны были такими быть. Но в любом случае, я запомнил, а как поменять?

Comment: Я в толк не возьму, здесь часть вопроса невидимым текстом для избранных написана чтоли? :) Что менять? Зачем менять? Какие индексы? Вопрос же про поиск, да и задача, опять же, решена...

Comment: Запоминать адреса `int * minp ;` `minp = & ( arr [ i ] [ j ] ) ;` и делать `swap ( * minp , * maxp ) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Максимальный и минимальный элемент вы уже нашли, теперь в тех местах где вы их сохраняете, сохраните также индексы и передайте в эту функцию:

```
 void swap(const int maxI, const int maxJ, const minI const minJ, float** matrix)
 {
       const float tmp = matrix[maxI][maxJ];
       matrix[maxI][maxJ] = matrix[minI][minJ];
       matrix[minI][minJ] = tmp;
 }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]